# Decode string in C#

Tags: c#, decode

I have an invalid text as following  `"Suite Ex&eacute;cutive"` while parsing using **JSON**.

Do you know any idea of how to **decode** this text in **C#** ? Thanks

Comment: You might want to add some code and explain what you are doing and why. I for one have no idea what you mean.

Comment: It's html encoded.  You need to html decode it.  Plenty of resources about this.

Comment: "*I did it because in here, it can be decoded*" can you explain where? what u did?

Comment: @KevinHendricks: &eacute; => é

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if are using ASP.NET you can try

[HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

class MyNewClass
{
public static void Main()
{
    String myString;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string having '&' or '\"'  in it: ");
    myString = Console.ReadLine();
    // String myEncodedString;
    // Encode the string.

    // myEncodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString);
    // Console.WriteLine("HTML Encoded string is " + myEncodedString);
       StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();
    // Decode the encoded string.
    // HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myEncodedString, myWriter);
    HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myString, myWriter);
    Console.Write("Decoded string of the above encoded string is " +
                   myWriter.ToString());

    Console.Read();
}
```

}

And on **.Net 4.0**

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(..)
```

Comment: +Ve. Nice code Clark, but edited it. Encoding is not required, simply decode the HTML, and the expected output will show. Cheers!